# Find solution set $\sqrt{x-5} + 5 =0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find solution set :

$\sqrt{x-5} + 5 =0$

Is there a solution to a set of complex numbers ?

Answer (score 4):

There are two square roots of any nonzero complex number.  Without further specification, it's not clear which is meant by $\sqrt{x-5}$.
If you allow both square roots, $x=30$ is the solution.  If you mean the principal branch of the square root, there are no solutions.

Comment: Perhaps there was an edition to the question but I can't see how $\;30\;$ solves the question that appears *right now*, which in my opinion has no real solutions.

Comment: If you permit complex roots, then I would read $\sqrt{30-5}+5$ as $\{-5,5\}+5$, which I suppose could be interpreted as $\{0,10\}$. I'm not sure I'd call that a solution here ("equal" to $0$). Even though it's clear what you mean.

Maybe if "If you allow both square roots" were changed to "If you mean the non-principle branch of the square root"?

Comment: Both $-5$ and $5$ are square roots of $30-5$.  So taking $x = 30$ and choosing $-5$ as the square root gives you a solution, if both square roots are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the solution here is $x = 30$.
The number $25$ which viewed as a complex number has two complex roots: $-5$ and $5$.
So if $x=30$, then $\sqrt{x-5} + 5 = 0$.

Also note that $25$ is the only number which has a complex root of $-5$.
This proves $30$ is the only solution.

This is some sort of synthetic solution.

If you want an analytic solution then write $x=a+b.i$,
move the 5 to the right, raise to the power of 2 and see what happens.

Comment: $\sqrt{30-5}+5=0\Rightarrow 5+5=10 \neq0$

The area of the square root positive integers and zero

Comment: No, $\sqrt{30-5}$ gives two values when viewed as a complex number. It's not just equal to 5.

Comment: Write $x=a+b.i$, move the 5 to the right, raise to the power of 2 and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

No.  There is no solution because $\sqrt{}$ is *by definition* non-negative.

However $\pm\sqrt{x-5} + 5 = 0$ does have a solution.

$\pm\sqrt{x-5} + 5 = 0$

$\pm\sqrt{x-5} = -5$

$(\pm\sqrt{x-5})^2 = (-5)^2$

$x-5 = 25$

$x = 30$.

But seriously.  You are NOT allowed to say $\sqrt{x-5} = -5$.  You just can't.  It's against the rules.

Comment: The OP is talking complex numbers. Non-negative has no meaning here.

Comment: $\sqrt{}$ is ill-defined in complex numbers and should be avoided.  We allow that $\sqrt{-1} = i$ but rarely do we allow $\sqrt{-1} = -i$.  The symbol $\sqrt{}$ implies a single value and not a multiple set of possible values.    Care must be taken to to express multiple possible values.  The statement "what is the solution to $\sqrt{v} = w$" is not properly asked.

Comment: OK, I see your point. Well, it depends how we define it, I have been taught simply that it's a multi-valued function. So... no problem. The complex number 30 is the solution. That's what I meant in my answer but seems people don't like it :)

Comment: This demonstrates we must be careful.  The solution in this case isn't strictly complex but simply negative.  Maybe you are right though.  I can't remember how I was taught.  But for real numbers (which this is) this can be a real bugaboo.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity I just applied this to n=2 and z=25 instead of z=unity. Never mind.

Answer (score 0):

In order to  have a real solution the implied $\pm$ before the radical sign should have negative sign, $ x= 30 $ is the solution. Other solution is complex.

Note that for a complex solution one takes care of both signs automatically. Like in quadratic equation  $ x^2 - 8 x + 25 =0 \, $ the roots are $ 4 \pm 3 i $,